# Reduce x axis of Test Result Trend in Jenkins job

Tags: testing, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that has been running for a while. When I want to check the Test Result Trend graph it's unreadable (it shows too many builds). I want to restrict the x axis to a limited number of builds (lets say 10). You can see what I mean [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4eAt.png).

Is there a way to configure this?

Comment: You can do that by deleting old builds. ;)

Comment: Peter, I think you're into something. Today I restarted the server and  the number of builds shown got smaller. Now it is readable! But the funny thing is that I don't any log rotation rule for this job. Weird...